# Query com intervalo de data com uma variável

Tags: sql

Sou novo no SQL e estou quebrando a cabeça para montar uma query que me retorne os resultados desejados.

Tenho um campo cujo formato da data é o seguinte: `2018-12-13T18:01:16.573-02:00`.

Tenho uma variável `$Período` cujos valores são (mês/Ano): `12/2017`, `01/2018`, `02/2018`, etc.

Esta consulta funcionou:

```
SELECT *
    FROM nomedatabela
    WHERE TO_CHAR(colunadata, 'MM/YYYY') = ($PERIODO)
```

No entanto, o período que quero consultar ao selecionar a variável é o seguinte:

- Ao selecionar a variável cujo valor seja `02/2018`, a consulta busque os registros de `06/01/2018` a `05/02/2018`;
- Ao selecionar a variável cujo valor seja `03/2018`, a consulta busque os registros de `06/02/2018` a `05/03/2018`;
- e assim por diante.

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisaria controlar as datas iniciais e finais, já que não quer se basear no mês completo (de *1* a *30/31*). Feito isso, basta comparar a `colunadata` com estas duas:

```
SELECT *
FROM nomedatabela
WHERE TO_CHAR(colunadata, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('06/', $periodo), '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
  AND TO_CHAR(colunadata, '%d/%m/%Y') <= CONCAT('05/', $periodo)
```

Explicando melhor as chamadas o que acontece no `DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('06/', $periodo), '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)`..

- `CONCAT()` -> adiciona o dia para pesquisa (*05* ou *06*, para início e fim do período);
- `STR_TO_DATE()` -> transforma a *string* montada (ex "06/02/2018") em uma data;
- `DATE_ADD()` -> adiciona (remove, no caso) um período da data;
- `INTERVAL -1 MONTH` -> seleciona o intervalo especificado para o *date_add* (no caso, *- um mês*)

Comment: Boa tarde colega! Primeiramente gostaria de agradecer pela resposta. No entanto tentei aqui e não deu, primeiro o seguinte erro: pq: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "$". Então alterei para SELECT *
FROM nomedatabela
WHERE TO_CHAR(colunadata, '%d/%m/%Y') >= DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('06/', '$periodo'), '%d/%m/%Y'), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
  AND TO_CHAR(colunadata, '%d/%m/%Y') <= CONCAT('05/', '$periodo') e deu o seguinte erro: pq: erro de sintaxe em ou próximo a "MONTH".

Comment: @dougvolei qual seu banco de dados? o exemplo montado foi em _mysql_, onde esse erro não deveria acontecer.

Comment: Bom dia! O meu banco é Postgresql. Consegui da seguinte forma: SELECT * 
FROM nomedatabela
WHERE colunadata BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(CONCAT('06/', $PERIODO), 'DD/MM/YYYY')- INTERVAL '1 MONTH'), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR((TO_DATE(CONCAT('05/', $PERIODO), 'DD/MM/YYYY')), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD/MM/YYYY') Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Buscando em um intervalo de tempo com o comando abaixo, será retornado todos os registros dentro deste período.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE coluna_data BETWEEN 'data01' AND 'data02';
```

Como esta trazendo apenas mês/ano, talvez seja necessário realizar uma concatenação, pelo exemplo que vc deu me parecem que são datas fixas do dia 6 de um certo mês até o dia 5 do próximo mês.

Ao que me parece está usando PHP, não tenho experiência com php, então não posso te falar como trabalhar com as datas ai (provavelmente você já saiba), mas o sql que fará a consulta da forma que você explicitou é este ai.

> Fonte:
>   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp